# identity of Euler's totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $p$ be a prime and $\varphi(n)$ be Euler's totient function and $m,n$ be natural numbers. Then $\varphi(p^k)=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$ and $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)(n)$ and $\varphi(p)=p-1$.But this
$$
\varphi(p^k)=\varphi(p)^k=(p-1)^k\neq \frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}=\varphi(p^k)
$$
bothers me. Where is the mistake here?

Comment: usually Euler's totient function is denoted $\phi(n)$

Comment: Did you mean $\sigma(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}=p^{k-1}(p-1)=p^k\left(1-\dfrac1p\right)$?

Comment: That's not the Euler's totient function. That's the "sum of divisors" function

Comment: sum of divisors function $\sigma(p)$ should be $p\color{blue}+1$

Comment: yes youre right. i edited. now its $\varphi$ everywhere

Comment: $\phi (mn)$ only equals $\phi(m)\phi(n)$ if $\gcd(m,n) =1$.  As $\gcd(p,p)\ne 1$ we do not have  $\phi(p^k)=(\phi p)^k$.  And $\phi(p^k)= (p-1)p^{k-1}\ne \frac {p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(mn)$ is a multiplicative function,
which means that
$\sigma(mn)=\sigma(m)\sigma(n)$
when $m$ and $n$ are
relatively prime.

A function $f$ is totally multiplicative
when $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$
for all $m$ and $n$.
As shown by your example,
$\sigma$ is not
totally multiplicative.